# Pandas - Numpy Select Join based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello Pythoneers and Pythonistas...

What is the best way of joining my DF column to a list of words in other languages (e.g. French, German)?

Basically, using the column country I would like to join my OneCol with different lists. I wrote the code below, but it returns an empty column. I think the logic is good, but perhaps I am missing something as I am a beginner. I tried writing an if-elif-else statement. My aim is to clear the strings from misspelled words for each language. Many thanks in advance for your help.

My dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3, 4],
    'Country': [1,2,3,12],
    'OneCol': ['I like this', 'Je ne sais pas', 'Niet', 'keine gar nicht ']
})
```

My Code:

```
conditions = [new_df["Country"].isin(['1','2','12']), 
              new_df["Country"]=='3', 
              new_df["Country"]=='4',  
              new_df["Country"]=='5', 
              new_df["Country"]=='6', 
              new_df["Country"]=='10']

applied_actions =  [new_df['OneCol'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(set(row.split()) & set(words.words())))), 
                    new_df['OneCol'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(set(row.split()) & set(list_fr)))), 
                    new_df['OneCol'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(set(row.split()) & set(list_de)))),
                    new_df['OneCol'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(set(row.split()) & set(list_it)))),
                    new_df['OneCol'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(set(row.split()) & set(list_es)))),
                    new_df['OneCol'].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(set(row.split()) & set(list_se))))]


new_df['ResultG'] = np.select(conditions, applied_actions, default=None)
```

Comment: `words.words()`, `list_fr`, `list_de`, etc. are undefined in this code snippet. What would you output look like given this dataframe?

Comment: Hey Henry, `words.words()` is a NLTK module, while `list_fr`, `list_de` are basically just words in those languages. I am using these lists to validate my strings. Let's say we have the string: `'Free from commercial or poltcal influence'` the code will only return: Free from commercial or influence. Because political is misspelled I will not count it, it will consider it invalid. The overall output would be a column ResultG that will count valid words in those languages. Basically, I am checking for misspelled words/giberish.

Comment: I even tried this: 
`to_be_set =np.where(new_df['Country'].isin([1,2,12])), set(words.words()), np.where((new_df['Country'] == 3), set(list_fr),None))` It returns a weird tuple.